# My delegate is never trigger in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, delegates

I created an API in .net core with C# that has a collection of elements. That collection has a delegate that is triggered when a new element is added (is working). The problem is that I can't make it work unless I subscribe to the delegate from the controller.

Current scenario:

```
    [HttpPost("welcome")]
    public IActionResult Welcome([FromBody] MyClient newClient)
    {
        ClientsDataStore.Current.clients.Push(newClient);
        return Ok(newClient);
    }
```

I created the class MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ILogger<MyClass> logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        ClientsDataStore.Current.clients.ElementAdded += ListenClients;
    }

    public async void ListenClients(object sender, MyClient e)
    {
        logger.LogDebug($"New client added");

        if (e.VirtualMachine)
        {
            await ProcessVMAsync(e);
        }
        else
        {
            await ProcessDesktopAsync(e);
        }
    }
 }
```

I tried to register the class in **public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)** like this:

```
services.AddTransient<MyClass>();
```

With that scenario, the delegate is never triggered, but if I use:

```
    [HttpPost("welcome")]
    public IActionResult Welcome([FromBody] MyClient newClient)
    {
        ClientsDataStore.Current.clients.ElementAdded += ListenClients;

        ClientsDataStore.Current.clients.Push(newClient);
        return Ok(newClient);
    }
```

Then the event is triggered.

I would like to know what I am missing here and how could I accomplished this.

**UPDATE**:

I changed the approach of the solution. I am going to have a background service checking every 10 seconds if the collection has a new element.

Comment: You should look up the life-time of AddTransient objects, and forget about using events in asp.net.

Comment: You're aware that your class above will never get freed up and you'll have a memory leak? events holds a reference to the subscribed object and unless you unsubscribe, there will always be an reference for it and hence never collected by the garbage collection. Also `async avoid` should **NEVER** be used, except for UI event handlers. Last but not least `MyClass` is never resolved or instantiated. Just registering it to the IoC do not mean it will get instantiated. It will only be instantiated when its really required for the first time, not before

Comment: @HenkHolterman what do you mean by _"forget about using events in asp.net"_? Isn't recommended?

Comment: No, asp.net is stateless and events require a statefull environment. Everything you use gets reconstructed on each new request.

Comment: In any ways, you could *warm up* your 'MyClass'  in `Configure` method, but that pattern is dirty anyways and you will get a lot of troubles (MyClient is transient and will be disposed at the end of the request, but you are using `async void`, so your controller action won't wait for the competition. This results in the request ending, and all (disposable) transient and scoped object will be disposed which may happen long before your callback finished (or even before it started). Better use a loosely coupled pub/sub or a scheduling library (such as quart or hangfire)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: What makes you think so? `ClientsDataStore` appears be singleton by the pattern its accessed (and not injected in `MyClass`). The singleton pattern usually involves calling `MyClass.Instance` or `MyClass.Current`

Comment: Thank you @Tseng. Could you explain me better about the memory leak? How could I solve the problem with the _async void_? As long as I know all the delegates have to be void, isn't right ? An about your _Last but not least_ (most important to me ;) ) I replaced: 
`services.AddTransient<Listeners>();`
by:
`Listeners test1 = new Listeners(LoggerFactory);`
And looks like it is working now. Is this the best approach?

Comment: @Tseng - yes ClientsDataStore could be a singleton (static). It shouldn't be, of course.

Comment: @Tseng You are right, ClientsDataStore is a singleton. But I have a list of clients in memory that I need to have it accessible from every endpoint. Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: The answer would be to inject the `ClientDataStore` into the controller, with the eventhandler already attached.

Comment: This sounds like a good case for an event bus. Here's an example, although it's perhaps a bit dated: http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/04/01/event-bus-implementation.html. Or you could inject functions/delegates to execute directly into your class. Those functions could be static classes or methods on classes resolved by the container.